# Android: ListView in LinearLayout let's other layout children disappear

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a simple LinearLayout with a few children. The whole activity design is basically copied from the Google BluetoothChat example. The LinearLayout contains 2 ListViews for displaying paired bluetooth devices and bluetooth devices that can be found (if they're discoverable).

The problem: If there are too many paired devices, the first ListView takes up the whole screen, so that the ScanButton is not visible anymore. Shouldn't there always be enough space for the ScanButton, since i'm working with android:weight.

Here's the xml-code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#666"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="@string/deviceList_title_paired_devices"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#666"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="@string/deviceList_title_other_devices"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/new_devices"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_scan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scan"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put 0dp for the height for both of the listviews and weight 1:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `layout_weight` to all the views and not just the `ListView`s.

Comment: If layout weight is removed, then the same thing will occur if the `ListView` contains more elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

As that will cause the list views to grow to fit all the content.